# What is the best way to migrate a large SQL Database to Azure SQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, azure, database-migration

I have to migrate an existing database in Azure SQL. Currently the db is ~400 Gb large. I've tried using the SQL Database Migration Wizard from codeplex (https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/), due to the fact that my database isn't quite compatible with SQL Azure (missing cluster indexes, index fill factors, etc. ) which the tool manages to 'fix' somehow. The problem with this tool is that I've started it about 10 days ago and it is still copying (one thing to mention is that the database is stored on a VM in Azure in the same zone). This won't work for me. Any possible solutions?

I've tried exporting a .bacpac from the SQL Server Management Studio (2014), but even if I try fixing all the incompatibilities I still get new ones. It's a never ending process so I gave up this solution.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You have to know what the tool does,if it still fixes your  issues transparently for you ,it will take time.But please first try to understand requirements ,otherwise you may face issues

Comment: After taking a look at the resulted SQL I've noticed that what it does is that it removes the incompatible sql like fillfactor, full-text search catalog, full text indexes and so on. I've created a script that should recreate the full-text catalog, indexes and stored procedures that use them. However I still have no idea about the clustered index issue, how is it fixed.

Comment: Does the database need to be converted to Azure SQL? Or would a SQL Server VM in Azure suffice? Also, you could "fix" the incompatibilities over time yourself, and then eventually migrate.

Comment: Chris, it's already on a SQL Server VM in Azure, so the answer is yes, it needs to be converted to Azure SQL. Probably I will try to "fix" the incompatibilities and then migrate.